# Can't Setup Npm Test Script for Karma on Windows

Tags: karma-jasmine

I've installed Karma in a test project following a guide from Pluralsight. However the instructor was using a mac and when I went to setup my test script following his example it didn't work. I've browsed the web for an hour with no solution.

In package.json in the "scripts" tag: "Test": "./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start karma.conf.js"

I tried everything from setting the file path all the way from my C:\ drive, reinstalling karma, making sure karma-cli was installed, re-starting my computer and still nothing worked. I get errors like "." is not a recognized command, file path not found ect...

Is there an easy way to set this up on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I changed this to: "test": "karma start C:/%PATH_TO_MY_CONF%/karma.conf.js"

That fixed this issue but I'd like to know if there's an easier way without having to set the full path to the conf file.

Thanks.